# Getting data from Postgres through Linked server of SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to get the data from PostgreSql db through linked server of the SQL Server. But getting the following error on running this query

```
select * from openquery(SALESFORCE,'select closeddate
                                    from case 
                                    where closeddate > convert(datetime2, "2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000")');
```

Output:

```
OLE DB provider "DBAmp.DBAmp" for linked server "SALESFORCE" returned message "Error: MALFORMED_QUERY: 
where closeddate > convert(datetime2, "2020-01-01
                           ^
ERROR at Row:3:Column:28
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
Cannot execute the query "select closeddate
                                    from case1 
                                    where closeddate > convert(datetime2, "2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000")" against OLE DB provider "DBAmp.DBAmp" for linked server "SALESFORCE". 

Completion time: 2021-04-22T03:00:25.5943467-04:00
```

Where I am getting wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is datetime2 is not a postgres data type:

```
convert(datetime2, "2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000")
```

The openquery statement exucute in the target database the query between '' so it must be written in the targewt dialect

try this

> select * from openquery(SALESFORCE,'select closeddate from case where
> closeddate > cast(''2020-01-01'' as date)')

Comment: But it **is** a SQL Server datatype - and it's SQL Server that's being queried?

Comment: If I have understood right, the linked server is pointing to a postgesql server. So the query sent by the openquery command to the server behind linked server has to be in target server dialect.

Comment: My apologies - you are correct - on rereading the question (which I should have done in the first place!), I realise my error. Best...